# Logging from Custom Tomcat Realm

Tags: tomcat, logging

This is probably a very dumb question, but I can't seem to find the answer to it.  I have a custom Realm for Tomcat, utilized at the Context level.  I would like to log failed and successful logins.

Is there some way for me to designate a file, or get a reference to an existing file, that will let me write explicit log lines to it from inside the Realm's authenticate function?

I have tried setting up a log4j file and a JUL file and calling getLogger and tried to write to it, no luck.  I also tried getLogger("catalina") in hopes I could access the internal logging process with no luck either.  Any help from out there?

Answer (score 0):

Does you custom Realm extend `org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase`?

There's a protected attribute `org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.containerLog` (which is an instance of `org.apache.juli.logging.Log`) which you'll have access to. This seems to be the approach for logging in many of the `org.apache.catalina.realm.*` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

using containerLog proved very straightforward.

The benefit is that you leverage the server logging configuration, particularly good in Tomcat 7, where JULI is used (as an improvement over commons logging).

The only thing I didn't like is the API is that of commons logging, not so friendly as that of slf4j for instance.
But you can also configure slf4j over log4j, in which case you'll have to add the JAR files in tomcat/lib, so that the parent class loader sees them when instantiating your realm.

One more thing you need to pay attention to: don't log anything in the realm constructor! I had to do some custom initialization (load a custom file) and I added some elementary logging and ended with a nasty NullPointer - the containerLog is not initialized in the constructor, but in method initInternal(). Override that, make sure you call the super.initiInternal () which initializes the logger and there you go.